# JavaScript error on small script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a small Greasemonkey script to change the value of a few elements when they appear on a page (through DOM modification).

I am just a Greasemonkey user, and I have no experience in JavaScript. I get this error: `the expression is not a legal expression.` (line: result =...)

I'd also like to know if there are any more errors I need to correct.

Here is my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        myscript
// @namespace   http://www.google.com
// @include     http://mysite/
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

function waitForKeyElements (selectorTxt, actionFunction) {
    if (getElementByXPath(selectorTxt) == null) {
       var timeControl = setInterval (function () {
                    waitForKeyElements (selectorTxt, actionFunction);
                },
                300
            );
    } else {
        clearInterval (timeControl);
        actionFunction();
    }
}

var getElementByXPath = function (path) {
  result = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
  return result.singleNodeValue;
};

function myFunc (jNode) {
    getElementById("foo1").setValue("foo2");
}

waitForKeyElements ("foo3", myFunc);
```

Comment: What line throws this error?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. Let me edit. Well it's line "result =..."

Comment: Which browser are you using? I doubt document.evaluate will work in IE and older browers.

Answer (score 1):

It complains that the value of `path` is not a valid XPath selector. From what I can see, you're passing the value `foo3` which means a tag `<foo3>` - probably not what you want. Try `//*[@id='foo3']` instead, see e.g. http://ejohn.org/blog/xpath-css-selectors/ for more xpath examples.

Comment: You're right. My actual xpath is of the form //h2[contains(., 'myText')] but apparently 'contains' (which is valid xpath) does not work ... How could I emulate this ?